# Log in RStudio with AWS EC2 instance

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio, rstudio-server

I managed to follow all the steps to create EC2 instance and install R Server on it.

But now when I go to RStudio to connect (which looks something like "ec2-[*Public IP*]-.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8787")
I am asked a username and a password but I did not configure any:

[image]

I tried rstudio (username) and rstudio (password) but it does not work.
Anyone knows how I can find the username and the password to connect?
Thanks.
M

Comment: I'm having the same problem when launching an RStudio image from AWS Marketplace. I asked [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/cannot-log-in-to-aws-rstudio-server-and-workbench-instead-see-error-unauthorized-user/126381) and will provide an answer here if I figure out what's going on..

Answer (score 3):

If this is using the AMI from http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/, the default password recently changed to the instance ID of the EC2. A code starting with `i-` and 17 alphanumeric characters, for example.

Username is still `rstudio`.

Comment: I've tried this username and my instance id as password combo, but it is not working at the moment (Error: Incorrect or invalid username/password). so I will burn it down and try again.

Comment: I did burn my previous instance down, started a new one, but made a new key pair and I can now login to RStudio on AWS. Only other thing I changed was a smaller instance. Following instructions from here: makinhttps://jagg19.github.io/2019/08/aws-r/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a user/password in Linux and use it to log in

```
#add user(s)
useradd username
echo username:password | chpasswd
```

here is a detailed blog from on [running R on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/running-r-on-aws/)

Comment: Thanks again Sudharsan ;) But it tells me: _-bash: /usr/sbin/useradd: Permission denied_

Comment: try sudo useradd

Comment: tried too but does not work either, please see below

Comment: run `chown -R user1:users /home/user1` and then run `useradd -d /home/user1 user1`

Comment: I created user1 but the command $ echo user1:password | chpasswd gives me : **"chpasswd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later."**

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue (I believe there is no ubuntu password for an AWS EC2 Instance and R studio requires one).

You can add a new user by typing the following: `sudo adduser YOURUSERNAME` and follow the terminal instructions (press enter to skip the info you do not want to give). Head over to the IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8787 and you should be able to log in now.

How to install R studio 3.4.4, upgrade to 3.6.0 and add a username (Ubuntu 18):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install -y r-base r-base-dev

sudo apt install gdebi-core

wget https://download2.rstudio.org/server/bionic/amd64/rstudio-server-1.2.1335-amd64.deb


sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.2.1335-amd64.deb

sudo chmod 777 -R /usr/local/lib/R/site-library

sudo adduser YOURUSERNAME

#########
# Upgrade R
echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade -y

sudo apt-get install -y r-base r-recommended r-base-dev

# Rstudio dependency issues (when installing devtools) - I installed from an AWS EC2 account so I need to change my root password.

sudo passwd root
su root
apt-get -y build-dep libcurl4-gnutls-dev
```